# Filter Pushes by Type

Tags: pushbullet

I'm working on building a `bash` script that will listen for pushes of the type `link` which will then extract just the URL and write it to a local file.

The idea is to be able to gather links I find and save them for automated processing later.

However, it doesn't appear that the API allows you to filter by `type` - only by `active`, `modified_after`, `cursor`, and `limit` - which seems a bit sparse to me, but oh well.

Since `type` isn't a filterable option, I'm assuming that I will need to add an additional step to parse the JSON returned and filter out any that don't have the type I'm looking for, then pass those to another step to extract the link and write it down to a file.

Before I go bashing (heh) my head against the wall writing this, is anyone aware of something that will already handle this, or at least keep me from re-inventing part of the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using `jq` to process and filter the json payload, allowing me to only select the types of pushes that I want.